# Sitecore: Find Item from sitecore for the checked values in a checkBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7.2

I have a list of items as follows on my page. All the names shown below are items in Sitecore.

[image]

Now I want to check which items the user has selected and then get their ids(sitecore Item ID) on a button click.  With the below mentioned code I can get the name but how I can get the Id (sitecore Item ID) of selected values?

```
// a temporary string to store the selected values
string values = "";

// A loop to check if each checkbox is selected then get the value
foreach (ListItem objItem in cblFoodItems.Items)
{
    if (objItem.Selected)
    {
        values += objItem.Value + ",";
    }
}
```

A bit more detail in case you like to know, how I am showing the items in the `checkBoxList`.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="cblFoodItems"  RepeatColumns="4"/>
```

**Code Behind**

```
Item foodFldr = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{42808F4D-5335-4BB6-911B-9B79E50CFE99}");

foreach (var foodItem in foodFldr.Children)
{
    var newListItem = new ListItem(foodItem.Name);
    cblFoodItems.Items.Add(newListItem);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code behind to:

```cs
foreach (var foodItem in foodFldr.Children)
{
     var newListItem = new ListItem(foodItem.Name, foodItem.ID.ToString());
     cblFoodItems.Items.Add(newListItem);
}
```

It will still display the `Name` of your item to the end users, but the value will be `ID` instead of item name.

Comment: Thanks man! I have checked your code and now I am getting the ids.